Rabbit MQ Recovery connection/channel/consumer with DLX failed
I have 2 queues, I have enabled the AutomaticRecoveryEnabled parameter set to true to allow automatic reconnection in my application.

QueueTest is the main queue that receives messages.
QueueTestRetry is the DLX queue that receives messages that the
consumer cannot process, for example, during an application
exception.

However, it does not work when I specify the x-dead-letter-exchange parameters. Here is the error in the logs:

operation queue.declare caused a channel exception precondition_failed: inequivalent arg 'x-dead-letter-exchange' for queue 'QueueTestRetry' in vhost '/': received none but current is the value 'tdi.retry.exchange' of type 'longstr'

The configuration of my queues is as follows:
QueueTest contains the following parameters:
x-queue-type: quorum
x-max-in-memory-length: 50
x-dead-letter-exchange: tdi.wait.exchange
x-dead-letter-routing-key: QueueTest

QueueTestRetry contains the following parameters:
x-queue-type: quorum
x-max-in-memory-length: 50
x-dead-letter-exchange: tdi.retry.exchange
x-dead-letter-routing-key: QueueTest

However, if I do not specify the x-dead-letter-exchange and x-dead-letter-routing-key parameters, the reconnection works without error.
Is the AutomaticRecoveryEnabled parameter limited when using DLX?
I'm using RabbitMQ 3.11.11

There is an issue, the .NET library does not make a copy or deep clone of the arguments dictionary, and I'm actually changing the arguments for when recovery happens. Google Rabbitmq's users create a pull request : here and conversations with complete program is here
